# some problems with IntegerType in cassandra

Tags: integer, cassandra, phpcassa

Why I am getting such symbols "N���" from the column with IntegerType?
in cassandra-cli.bat it is showing normally, as integer.
I'm using phpcassa...maybe I need to convert this value, like I'm doing with UUID

```
UUID::import($uuid)->string
```

but with other certain function?

Comment: You should put your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks to all!I found a solution.
just needs to 
    *unpack('N', $value);*
or to modify a bit phpcassa's ColumnFamily class, it uses this(unpack) function, but this function is *private***